# What's $\kappa=\min\{\nu : [0, \omega_1)\text{ embedds into }\mathbb{R}^\nu\}$?

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

What's the least $\kappa$ such that $[0, \omega_1)$ embedds into $\mathbb{R}^\kappa$?

We have $\aleph_1\leq \kappa\leq \mathfrak{c}$ since $\mathbb{R}^{\aleph_0}$ is metrizable and $|C([0, \omega_1))| = \mathfrak{c}$.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't follow how $|C([0, \omega_1))| = \mathfrak{c}$ implies the upper bound on $\kappa$.  Can you explain?

Comment: @PatrickR If $X$ is Tychonoff, then $X$ embedds into $\mathbb{R}^{C(X)}$ by the map $x\mapsto (f(x))_{f\in C(X)}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar argument but maybe a little simpler, showing that $\omega_1=[0,\omega_1)$ embeds into $\{0,1\}^{\omega_1}$, which itself embeds as a subspace of $\mathbb R^{\aleph_1}$:

Write $X=\{0,1\}^{\aleph_1}$ for convenience.
The map $\phi:\omega_1\to X$ mapping $\alpha\in\omega_1$ to $f_\alpha=1_{[\alpha,\omega_1)}$ is continuous and a homeomorphism onto its image.

A typical nbhd of $f_\alpha$ in $X$ consists of those maps $g\in X$ with $g(\lambda_i)=0$, $g(\alpha)=1$ and $g(\mu_j)$ for a finite number of $\lambda_i<\alpha$ and $\mu_j>\alpha$.  A typical nbhd of $\alpha\in\omega_1$ consists of those ordinals $\lambda$ with $\beta<\lambda\le\alpha$ for some fixed $\beta<\alpha$.

From this it is easy to check that because each map in the image of $\phi$ has values all zero and then all one from a certain ordinal on, a typical nbhd above for $\alpha\in\omega_1$ maps into a typical nbhd above for $f_\alpha\in X$.  And similarly for inverse images from $\operatorname{im}(\phi)$.

Comment: I think you want to change $X$ to be $\{0, 1\}^{\aleph_1}$ because otherwise you'll only get $|g(\lambda_i)| < 1/2$ for instance, and so on.

Comment: @Jakobian Good point.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $f_\alpha = 1_{\{\alpha\}}$ for $\alpha<\omega_1$ a non-limit ordinal and $f_{\alpha, \beta} = 1_{(\beta, \alpha]}$ for $\alpha<\omega_1$ limit ordinal and $\beta<\alpha$. Then $f_\alpha, f_{\alpha, \beta}$ are continuous, separate points from closed sets, and there is $\aleph_1$ of them. Hence mapping induced by them is an embedding into $\{0, 1\}^{\aleph_1}$, so $\kappa = \aleph_1$.

By the same argument we can embedd $[0, \omega_\alpha)$ into $\{0, 1\}^{\aleph_\alpha}$.